# Passing PHP array to JavaScript object array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, for-loop

I have a table in a database with three columns, `prop_no`, `prop_name`, `prop_sc` in a database and I moved the entries of the last two columns into 2 PHP arrays `$propertyNameList` and `$propertyCodeList`.
Now I have a JavaScript class `Property` and an array `propList`. I need to move all the values from the two PHP arrays to this JS array using

```
  propList.push(new Property(1,<?php  echo json_encode($propertyNameList[0]); ?>,
                        <?php echo json_encode($propertyCodeList[0]); ?>));
```

using a for loop, where the 1st argument would be the counter variable and the PHP array indices must change with every iteration. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably suggest you restructure things a bit, but you can fairly easily do it with temporary parallel arrays.

Here we dump those parallel arrays out to the client-side code and then do the loop there in JavaScript:

```
(function() {
    var names = <?php echo json_encode($propertyNameList) ?>;
    var codes = <?php echojson_encode($propertyCodeList) ?>;

    for (var n = 0; n < names.length; ++n) {
        propList.push(new Property(names[n], codes[n]));
    }
})();
```

Or if you prefer the loop on the PHP side:

```
<?php
    $index = 0;
    for ($index = 0; $index < count($propertyNameList); ++$index) {
        echo 'propList.push(new Property(' . json_encode($propNameList[$index]) . ', ' . json_encode($propCodeList[$index]) . '));';
    }
?>
```

(I think, my PHP is fairly weak.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did this way and got exactly what I wanted.